# Windows API : a way to get monitor of the focus (active window)?

Tags: winapi

Using Windows API, is there a way to get the screen where is displayed the current active window.

Comment: At any given time, there are zero or more active windows. There is no such thing as *"the"* active window. You need to be more specific. Are you referring to the foreground window? It's also unclear, what *"get the screen"* is supposed to mean. Do you need to get the monitor, where a window resides? If so, how do you want to deal with a window, that straddles displays? Make sure to read [ask] to learn, what makes a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The rough steps are:

1. GetActiveWindow / GetForegroundWindow
2. GetWindowRect
3. GetDC
4. CreateCompatibleDC
5. CreateCompatibleBitmap
6. BitBlt

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the API cant do this directly.  A given window can be interacted with through a device context, but there is no way of determining which monitor in a multi-monitor system that window is displayed on with an API call.  Indeed it may be displayed on more than one.

The long answer is you can calculate it by retrieving the window's physical location on the desktop GetWindowRect(), converting it to screen coordinates with ClientToScreen() , and then calculating which of the enumerated display devices it is on.

I dont have the rep to post more than 2 links, but MSDN has the functions listed.

GetDC()

GetWindowRect()

ClientToScreen() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434(v=vs.85).aspx

EnumDisplayDevices()

EnumDisplaySettingsEx - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162612(v=vs.85).aspx